# How do I implement Role Provider in Keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak

I have a user table in my database and I have implemented a custom user provider for Keycloak so that my users can login with Keycloak. But I cannot use the roles tables from my database within Keycloak. Is it possible to use a role table from my database within Keycloak's roles?